# Find out DST safe time of last N days

Tags: c++, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Let's say today is Monday. I want to find out what is the date for last Wednesday.

the logic I thought is 
1) No of days difference from today to last saturday ( ie. 6 )
2) Substract those many seconds from today

```
time_t now = time(0);
// determine the no of day differences i.e 6
time_t lastWeekTime = now - (86400 * 6);
```

This is not DST safe. Can some one tell me what I need to take care here.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's correct: ["... time_t is almost always a integral value holding the number of seconds since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t). No DST here.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: It will be off by one day, for one hour per day, if the DST change happened an odd number of times since the start date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could convert the time_t using [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) to a tm struct. This struct contains the days as values - you can just add/subtract. You just have to make sure that you change the month/year if necessary. After you changed it correctly, you can use [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/) to convert it back.

Awkward but manageable. This way you don't need to know about DST but only about the number of days / month and month / year.

The better way would probably be to use [Boost Date Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dates don't have a notion of DST, that only applies to date-times, as you need a fractional part of the day to describe if you're before or after the switch.  So Fri, 01 Jun 2012 is always Fri, 01 Jun 2012, regardless how many DST switches happen on that day, or before or after that day.

Your way is already the correct way, `time()` will give you the number of seconds since the (unix) Epoch and that scale does not observe daylight-saving switches, so `lastWeekTime % 86400` will be exactly the same as `now % 86400` (as per your computation actually).  So if you only need the date just make sure not to print the time component, e.g. by subtracting `now % 86400` from the result and using only UTC functions (`gmtime()`/`timegm()`).

If you want something like: Today is Monday and there's an appointment at 11:00.  I want to move it exactly `N` days back in time.  Then use your algorithm to go from Monday `N` days back and set the time part manually:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
time_t then = now - 86400 * N;
time_t then_eleven = (then - then % 86400) + 11 * 3600;
```